# Stamp Bitmap on Path - Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Is there any easy way to stamp bitmaps along a line in Android? I've found the PathDashPathEffect class but that only allows Paths to be stamped, rather than bitmaps. It seems like it should be possible, but I'm not sure where to start.

I could obviously just draw bitmaps along the line, but it seems to me like that would be a bit more resource intensive, especially because I would not be doing it in native code.

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: I ended up just drawing bitmaps on the line. Not pretty, but works.

Comment: A small code example would be a good addition to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no API for this. You could use a BitmapShader to fill the path with a Bitmap but I don't think that's what you want.